# Nexus sonatype apache 2.4 proxy does not allow admin login

Tags: apache, security, reverse-proxy, nexus

I have just setup nexus 2.8.1 and a reverse proxy via the following directives in an Apache 2.4 configuration.

```
<Location /nexus>
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://nexushost.server:8082/nexus
    ProxyPassReverse http://nexushost.server:8082/nexus
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
</Location>
```

However, whenever I try to login it always fails with a invalid username/password or access to ui not enabled.

If I try the same access by going directly to the `http://nexushost.server:8080/nexus` page then I don't have any issues logging in with the same credentials.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from this directive:

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```

I guess you're doing that because you're using Basic auth in your Apache and you don't want the Authorization header to drift unto Nexus. Unfortunately Nexus uses the same header to perform authentication (you can verify this by opening the network analyzer of your browser).

I came up with the following strategies:

1. You perform basic auth in Apache and disable auth in Nexus, by giving anonymous all the rights for example. For obvious security reasons, you must make sure that Nexus is bound to 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0.
2. You disable basic auth in Apache (plus of course removing the above directive) and let Nexus perform the authentication.
3. You map your Apache user/passwords to those of Nexus. You'll need to remove the above directive to let the Authorization header propagate to Nexus. This gives you the advantage of not showing Nexus at all for unauthenticated users, while retaining the right management of Nexus. The only drawback is that you need to manage passwords in 2 places.
4. Same as 3 but to workaround the password management overhead, you set in nexus the same password for all your users (e.g 'nexus_password') then you make Apache rewrite the authorization header with this password. Here is an example of Apache configuration that does it:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteMap base64map prg:/usr/bin/b64

   <Location />
     RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.*)
     RewriteRule .* - [E=R_U:${base64map:%1:nexus_password}]
     RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic %{R_U}e"
   </Location>
   ```

   With `/usr/bin/b64` wrapping around `base64`:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   # MANAGED BY PUPPET
   # This is an apache RewriteMap interface for base64 : apache runs this program only once at startup
   # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap
   while read line; do
     echo -n $line | /usr/bin/base64
   done;
   ```

   Same as 1, make sure Nexus is bound to localhost.

Comment: Yes, I had added the basic auth on the Apache as it was a public server and I didn't want Nexus to carry out the authentication. I switched over to use nginx and got it working fine, but I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You have to map cookies to be passed through as well as a few other things. Check out the documentation in the Nexus book.

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html

Specifically the cookies are required for the UI to work in a browser.

Comment: The book says to map cookies "If you want to serve Nexus on a context path that is different than the one it has been configured for", which isn't the case. But +1 for the link.

Comment: You have to map the cookies as well since you are changing protocol. I have updated the books doc and will push it live shortly.

Comment: Unless you set the secure-only-flag or the http-only-flag, cookies are protocol agnostic. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1

Comment: @BrunoBieth Nexus always sends session cookies with HttpOnly flag. As of Nexus 2.11.1, the Secure flag is also configurable.